# open sets in a regular surface in $R^3$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

I am reading *Differential geometry of curves and surfaces* by Do Carmo.

Let S be a regular surface in $R^3$.

I wonder

How is open set of S defined?

Is a subset of S open if and only if it is the intersection of some open set in $R^3 with S?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the general definition of the subspace topology:

If $X$ in a subset of a topological set $Y$, an open set of $X$ for the subspace topology is the intersection of $X$ and an open set of $Y$.

Remark that this has nothing to do with differential topology.

Comment: Then is it true that a subset of S is open if and only if it is the intersection of S with some open set of R^3? Sorry I need to confirm.

Comment: Well, this is the definition I gave, isn't it ?

Comment: Sorry could you just answer yes or no to my question?

Comment: Of course, the answer is Yes. But you should have understood it yourself

Comment: Thanks I was just confused because in the abstract definition of surfaces not necessarily in $R^3$, open sets seem to be defined differently. That is why I am very confused.

Comment: Maybe you should precise your question, then.